# Filter maps whose key values contain a substring

Tags: clojure, maps, grouping, input-filtering

I have a set of maps I wish to filter. For instance, consider the set of maps

```
({:a "hi" :b 1} {:a "hello" :b 2} {:a "hellooo" :b 3})
```

I want to get

```
({:a "hello" :b 2} {:a "hellooo" :b 3})
```

As these two maps contain the substring `"hello"` under the key `:a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(filter #(re-find #"hello" (:a %)) 
        [{:a "hi" :b 1} {:a "hello" :b 2} {:a "hellooo" :b 3}])

;;-> ({:a "hello" :b 2} {:a "hellooo" :b 3})
```

Comment: I tried this in clooj and I only got the map with b=2 returned. I changed #"hello" to #"hello.*" and i got your outpout

Comment: My bad. Use `re-find` instead, it will return non-nil if the pattern is *contained* in the input, rather than if the whole input matches as `re-matches` does.